# Drawing tablet pen still drawing when just hovering

Tags: tablet, drawing, graphics-tablet

I have a Monoprice 10 x 6.25-inch drawing tablet, and here recently, there's been a huge issue. 
If I simply hover my pen over the screen of the tablet, the pen will respond as if I'm pressing down on the screen with the pen. 
I just recently bought this pen, and I'm afraid my only option now is to buy another one to replace it.

I've followed many other methods, such as taking the batteries out of the pen and putting them back, resetting the tablet, resetting the computer as a whole, and many more. But nothing has helped so far.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated, and I'm all ears for questions if you have any. :)

Answer (score 0):

nib broken? just try new nib and hope it'll fix it. if not, the pen OR tablet is broken.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too, I'm just not sure where I put the bag of new nibs at-

Comment: gotta find de bag of nibs o:

Comment: Update: I bought a new pack of nibs, but sadly, I'm still having the same issue. I'm really hoping it's not the tablet ;0;